# Subtract 1 from each element in the list in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list, `A`. I would like to subtract 1 from each element of the list. The desired output is shown below.

```
A=[5, 6, 7, 11]
```

The desired output is

```
A=[4, 5, 6, 10]
```

Comment: What is your question? Why did you add the `numpy` tag?

Comment: `A = [a - 1 for a in A]`

Comment: Can you show what you have done till now or your thought process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is

```
A = [*map(lambda x: x - 1, A)]
```

Code

```
a = [5, 6, 7, 11]
a = [*map(lambda x: x - 1, a)]
print(a)
```

Output

```
[4, 5, 6, 10]
```

The expression `lambda x: x - 1` returns a function object that accepts one argument and subtracts the argument by 1, returning the result. `map(lambda x: x - 1, a)` returns an iterator that applies this function to every item in the iterable (in our case, list) `a`. The `*` is the iterable unpacking operator.

This method is particularly useful if the operation you want to apply on each element is more complicated. Instead of creating an anonymous function (via `lambda`), you could define a function beforehand, with name, say, `foo`, and insert `foo` as the first argument instead.

For such a simple operation, you are better off directly doing (as first suggested by @SomethingSomething)

```
A = [i - 1 for i in A]
```

**Timings**

```
In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: a = [5, 6, 7, 11]
   ...: for i in range(len(a)):
   ...:     a[i] -= 1
   ...: 
327 ns ± 2.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [6]: %%timeit
   ...: a = [5, 6, 7, 11]
   ...: a = [*map(lambda x: x - 1, a)]
   ...: 
   ...: 
323 ns ± 1.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [7]: %%timeit
   ...: a = [5, 6, 7, 11]
   ...: a = [i - 1 for i in a]
   ...: 
   ...: 
233 ns ± 1.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the list and decrease the value of each number by 1.

```
A = [5, 6, 7, 11]

#original
print(A)

for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i] -= 1

#changed
print(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Integers in Python are **immutable**. Therefore, there is no option to modify the existing list elements. They can be replaced though. A possible solution is therefore to override the list by a copy, whose integers were subtracted:

```
A = [v-1 for v in A]
```

If there is a requirement to preserve the list instance `A` and not replace it by a new list instance, then as suggested in other answers, you can iterate and subtract ones from the items:

```
for i, v in enumerate(A):
    A[i] = v-1
```

Since integers are immutable, the subtracted values will actually be new integer instances, but the list `A` that contains them will stay the same instance.

Comment: @SomethingSomething is correct. While his answer assigns a new list to `A`, he did not mention lists are immutable.